# Antlr 3.2 Rewrite Rules

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I've recently started learning Antlr and downloading AntlrWorks 1.4 which supposedly includes Antlr 3.2.  Now, 3.2 is supposed to support the rewrite rules grammars like '->' but I've not been able to get even the simplest case I could construct to work either based on Lexer or Parser rules:

```
grammar TestRewrite;

ab  :   a b -> a;

a   :   A;
b   :   B;

A   :   'a';
B   :   'b';
```

When I try to compile this, I get the error:

```
[11:26:29] error(100): TestRewrite.g:3:13: syntax error: antlr: TestRewrite.g:3:13: unexpected token: a
```

Why is this.  The construction seems simple enough: ab should generate a tree where only the a node is captured.  Isn't that how you do it?  I can't get it to work with rooting ('^') or ignoring ('!') either.  I've very confused.

Answer (score 8):

options {output=AST;}

Comment: @TimeHorse, the `options {output=AST;}` should be placed directly after your `grammar TestRewrite;` statement.